# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'XXX.XXX.XXX'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use strongly typed dropdownlist for my application. I have textbox fields as well. But when i pass `@model Aayumitra.Models.RegisterViewModel
 @using Aayumitra.Models;` I am getting below error.

> > > The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'XXX.XXX.XXX'.

AccountViewModel

```
 public class RegisterViewModel
    {     

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Genders { get; set; }

    }
```

Controller

```
 private static List<SelectListItem> GetGenders()
        {
            AayumitraDBEntities db = new AayumitraDBEntities();
            List<SelectListItem> GenderList = (from p in db.Genders.AsEnumerable()
                                                 select new SelectListItem
                                                 {
                                                     Text = p.GenderType,
                                                     Value = p.GenderId.ToString()
                                                 }).ToList();


            //Add Default Item at First Position.
            GenderList.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Text = "--Select Gender--", Value = "" });
            return GenderList;
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/UpdatePatient
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult UpdatePatient()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> GenderList = GetGenders();
            return View(GenderList);
        }
```

View

```
@model Aayumitra.Models.RegisterViewModel
@using Aayumitra.Models;


                    @using (Html.BeginForm())
                    {
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="profile-container">
                                    <div class="profile">
                                        <img src="~/Content/images/logo.png" width="100" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="profile-info">
                                        <p>
                                            @Html.TextBox("FullName", User.Identity.Name.ToString(), new { @readonly = "readonly", @disabled = "disabled" })
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                        </div>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MiddleName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MiddleName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MiddleName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <div class="form-group">

                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gender, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.Gender, new SelectList(Model.Genders, "Value", "Text"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "Gender" })

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>


                    }
```

Comment: Can't you just have `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.Gender, Model.Genders, htmlAttributes...)`

Comment: @ediblecode,I changed dropdown code as you suggested but issue still exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your View is supposed to be for UpdatePatient, then you want to create a model of type RegisterViewModel and add Genders to it, and then pass that model to the View, like this:

```
        public ActionResult UpdatePatient()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> GenderList = GetGenders();
            return View(new RegisterViewModel
            {
                FirstName = "",
                MiddleName = "middle",
                LastName = "last",
                Genres = GenderList
            });
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I have more than 15 fields so I do not think that it will be a good approach of writing all fields like you did here. Please suggest me some other ways.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with a ViewModel having 15 fields.  If you would like you can build your viewmodel's fields in the controller above the return statement and then just return View(model) or you can even build the viewmodel in a separate class and then call ViewModelBulder.Build() in your controller and then pass that to your return statement.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. Do I have to change anything in View `@model Aayumitra.Models.RegisterViewModel`

Comment: i didn't notice anything needed to be changed no.